# How to validate a comma separated string using array in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to create a function in sql which will validate a comma separated string.

```
example: string will be like @str = 'AB,CD,EF,GH'
```

I have to check the string values  must be one of the following

```
 i.e (AB,EF,GH)
```

And `GH Cannot come alone` .

if it is true then function will return a true flag.

So, I want to ask how i can split this string into a array and compare that array to that predefined set of values..

Comment: Use string_split function to split it into single column table and use the , as separator.

Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx

You can change a compatibility level of database using the following command: ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? if not can you give an example of the output desired with a given input?

Answer (score 1):

This function will take your comma separated list and return a table, just like `STRING_SPLIT()` which I think is only available for SQL Server 2016. Then, you'll just `INNER JOIN` to the table based on your conditions. I usually set a table variable to the results of this function so I can reuse it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_split_string]
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DataRow NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (DataRow)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData, 
                @FoundIndex  + 1,
                LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (DataRow)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END

GO
```

Comment: I have already created a function to split the string and store into a table.. but i am not getting how can i compare those values to the predefined set of values.So that it can give me a true false flag.

Comment: I would recommend switching out your splitter for any of these. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings The performance of loop based splitters is just awful.