# Using In clause with SET clause

Tags: sql-server

I am using Declare/Set clauses to streamline a query. One of the fields includes multiple departments. Sometimes, I might want to limit to one department_id and other times I would like multiple departments. Is it possible to Set the @dept to include multiple department IDs?

```
declare @enddate datetime, @startdate datetime, @dxstartdate datetime, @dxenddate datetime,@ageanchor datetime,@activestart datetime, @activeend datetime, @dept numeric (18,0)

SET @enddate='2016-05-31' 
SET @startdate = '2015-06-01' 
SET @dxstartdate = '2015-06-01'
SET @dxenddate = '2016-05-31'
SET @ageanchor = '2016-05-31'
SET @activestart = '2014-06-01'
SET @activeend = '2016-05-31'
***SET @dept = in "dept1', 'dept2' ???(What do I put here?)***
```

Comment: You don't. A scalar variable will hold only a scalar value. If you want to hold multiple values you need to use a table variable or a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set `@dept` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` so that you can take in any number of departments. Then, `SET @dept = 'dept1,dept2,dept3'`. Now you have a comma separated list variable which you can split into a column, and `JOIN` to in your code. First you'll need a function to convert this comma separated list into a table. See: [How to validate a comma separated string using array in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572738/how-to-validate-a-comma-separated-string-using-array-in-sql/37573352#37573352) where I posted a function to do this, unless you are on SQL 2016 and in that case you can use `STRING_SPLIT()`. Either way, you are going to wind up with a column of departments which you'll `INNER JOIN` to in your `SELECT` statement to filter your data.