# Change the string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace

I have this stored procedure in which I am passing `@CourseID` as

```
|CRS0001095|CRS0001223|CRS0001224|CRS0001225|CRS0001229|CRS0001238|CRS000124
```

which is from a web application. But I want to replace this string as

```
'CRS0001095', 'CRS0001223', 'CRS0001224', 'CRS0001225', 'CRS0001229', 'CRS0001238', 'CRS000124'
```

so that I can pass this string to my query.

I tried `Replace` but that causes an error. How can I change that string?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LSS_e_test_sp]
    @TRANTYPE VARCHAR(30)='',
    @PARAM1 VARCHAR(30)='',
    @PARAM2 VARCHAR(30)='',
    @PARAM3 VARCHAR(30)='',
    @PARAM4 VARCHAR(30)='',
    @PARAM5 VARCHAR(3000)=''
AS
    DECLARE 
        @WORKORDERNO VARCHAR(20),
        @EVENTPOINT VARCHAR(30),
        @LASTEDITBY VARCHAR(30),
        @ERRMSG VARCHAR(500),
        @ProductionLine VARCHAR(100),
        @CourseID VARCHAR(3000),
        @OperatorsTraLevel VARCHAR(30),
        @reqOperatorLevel VARCHAR(30)

    IF @TRANTYPE = 'getOperatorLavel'
    BEGIN
        SET @WORKORDERNO = @PARAM1
        SET @EVENTPOINT = @PARAM2
        SET @LASTEDITBY = @PARAM3
        SET @CourseID = @PARAM5

        Print @WORKORDERNO
        Print @EVENTPOINT
        Print @LASTEDITBY
        Print @CourseID

        select @OperatorsTraLevel = MAX(convert(real, TraingLavel)) 
        from ftx_tm_courselevelMapping 
        where coursenumber in (@CourseID)

        print @OperatorsTraLevel

        RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: Even if you used `REPLACE()` to transform the string into the value you want, your query will still not work.  You can't use a variable in `IN()` like that.

Comment: @Siyual i checked that part.. if i pass the correct string its running fine.

Comment: @user6363065 I don't think so. Did you test it with a variable? Try `set @CourseID='''CRS0001095'',''CRS0001223'''` before the query. Does it work? (spoiler: no)

Comment: Note: you *can* do this, but you'll have to dynamically generate the entire query, not just the `IN` clause, and pass it to `exec`.

Comment: @Siyual is right.  The IN statement takes a list of comma separated values.  When you pass a variable, it doesn't matter that the text has commas in it, it considers the ENTIRE variable to be one item in the condition.

Comment: Here is a split string function that you can use to split your variable into a single column table which you can then INNER JOIN to in your `SELECT`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37573352/6167855

Comment: I would recommend any of the splitters found here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings They will perform FAR better than that looping splitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using @CourseID in a that IN Clause, so you can do something like

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = '|CRS0001095|CRS0001223|CRS0001224|CRS0001225|CRS0001229|CRS0001238|CRS000124';
declare @ret_list as table ( cr_id nvarchar(max) );
declare @pos int;
declare @cr_id nvarchar(max)

while CHARINDEX('|', @str) > 0
begin
    select @pos = CHARINDEX('|', @str);
    select @cr_id = substring(@str, 1, @pos-1);
    insert into @ret_list (cr_id) values (@cr_id);
    select @str = SUBSTRING(@str, @pos+1, LEN(@str) - @pos)

end
select * from @ret_list where cr_id not like ''
```

After that, replace the following:

```
 select @OperatorsTraLevel = MAX(convert (real, TraingLavel)) from ftx_tm_courselevelMapping where coursenumber in (@CourseID)
```

with

```
 select @OperatorsTraLevel = MAX(convert (real, TraingLavel)) from ftx_tm_courselevelMapping where coursenumber in (select cr_id from @ret_list where cr_id not like '')
```

and you should be golden!

Answer (score 1):

Try another route:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(coursenumber,@CourseID)>0
```

Don't even split `@CourseID` and select data where `coursenumber` is in your `@CourseID` string.

Comment: This seems like the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your MS SQL Server is 2016 then you can enjoy `string_split` function.

```
...where si in (select value from string_split(@CourseID,'|'))
```

Else if MS SQL Server is 2008 or newer then you can split the string in the query.

```
;with dat(x) as (
select cast( '<s>'+replace(@CourseID,'|','</s><s>')+'</s>' as xml)
)
select @OperatorsTraLevel = MAX(convert (real, TraingLavel)) 
from ftx_tm_courselevelMapping cross join dat
where coursenumber in (select t.v.value('.[1]','varchar(20)') from x.nodes('s') t(v))
```